# Two forms one view - Value is not coming from Form - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two forms and their models are related to each other and i am trying that both of them should get saved in database simultaneously.

My one form (sim_form) will be updated while my other form (payment_form) will be saved using the same button. I am using django Crisp-forms and as far as display is concerned both forms are being rendered. Similarly, i am also able to fetch data of sim_form based on value received to it (pk=id).

I am able to update data (save in database) in Sim model but value from Form is not coming into my Payment model, thats is why it gives me a validation error that "Column deposit_date cannot be null.

I have tried different solutions, as you can see from the code below.

```
def updatePayment(request, id):
    sim  = get_object_or_404(Sim, pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("i am in if1")
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST)
        # payment_form = payment_form.save(commit=False)
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(request.POST, instance=sim)
        try:
            if  sim_form.is_valid:
                print("i am in if")
                # payment_form = payment_form.save(commit=False)
                # sim_form = sim_form.save(commit=False)
                # payment_form.save()
                sim_form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("Payment has been updated"))
                if payment_form.is_valid():
                    print("i am in if paymemt")
                    payment_form.save()
            else:
                messages.warning(request, ("Data in fields is incorrect, please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request, ("Error: {}".format(e)))
    else:
        sim_form = UpdatePayment(instance=sim)
        payment_form = AddPaymentForm(request.POST)
    context = {'sim_form': sim_form,'payment_form': payment_form,}
    return render(request, 'payment/updatePayment.html', context)
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are form rendered in html ? Because you can't have nested html forms.

Comment: Do you mind telling through code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you render several forms with the `{% crispy %}` tag, you should follow the instructions [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#rendering-several-forms-with-helpers), because you don't want the crispy template tag to add the `<form>` tag, since you only need one `<form>` tag.

Instead, on each of your forms, set `self.helper.form_tag = False` and add both `{% crispy %}` tags inside your own `<form>` HTML tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was really struggling with it.